# Make a lookup on an array literal in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, lookup, literals

Making a lookup on an array is simple:

```
$array = array(0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two');
$text = $array[2]; // $text = 'Two'
```

But if I don't want the intermediate $array variable, is there any built in way of making a lookup an array literal?

Examples

```
$text = array(0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two')[2]; // Syntax error
$text = array_value(2, array(0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two')); // Unknown command
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of PHP5.5 you can do:

```
$text = array(0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two')[2];
```

For versions lower than 5.5 you'll have to code a function like `array_value()` on your own as there is no built in function for it. Like this:

```
function array_value($key, $array) {
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        throw new Exception('Array has no index ' . $key);
    }

    return $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: Well, that as a quick reply. I am stuck on 5.3 so I guess the workaround will have to do then. Thanks!

Comment: `I am stuck on 5.3 ` me too ;) But can't await 5.5

Comment: @Coderanonymous Was a typo, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
$array = array(0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two');
$pos = 2;

echo current(array_slice($array, $pos, 1));
```